# My implementation of insertion sort

Tags: java, sorting, insertion-sort

This is my implementation of insertion sort in java for doubly linked list. I have checked for many values and it gives me correct output. My question is:

1. I don't know how to calculate the algorithm time for this I mean O(n)
2. Can this be optimized? Can anyone point to code which is more optimized?

Note : Code uses sentinel node to that points to start of linked list i.e sentinel node.next points to starting node of linked list and sentinel node.PREV point to last node of linked list and head points to sentinel node.

```
public void sortInsertionAsce(){
            DListNode marker,aheadOfCurrent;;
            DListNode current = head.getNext();
            aheadOfCurrent = current.getNext();
            marker=current;
            while(aheadOfCurrent.getNext()!=current){
            if(marker.getItem()>aheadOfCurrent.getItem()){
                swap(aheadOfCurrent,marker);
                marker=aheadOfCurrent;
                    while(aheadOfCurrent.getPrev()!=current){
                        aheadOfCurrent=aheadOfCurrent.getPrev();
                        if(aheadOfCurrent.getPrev().getItem()>aheadOfCurrent.getItem()){
                            swap(aheadOfCurrent.getPrev(),aheadOfCurrent);
                        }
                    }
                    aheadOfCurrent=marker;
                }
                    marker=aheadOfCurrent;
                    aheadOfCurrent=aheadOfCurrent.getNext();
            }
         }
```

Comment: I am new to linked list and wanted an honest opinion from someone. This code works. Just wanted to know if this can be optimized.

Comment: This is a question for [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) .

Comment: @LeeAllan You do know that this question is four years old, I hope? I think you are a bit late at recommending Code Review...

Comment: @LeeAllan this question cannot be migrated, it is too old

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg I guess the feed doesn't care about date them. Good job there.

Comment: @LeeAllan I assume you are on the "active" page which is about when a question was last modified. This question was edited 13 minutes ago. There's your explanation. Mystery solved, case closed ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's O(N^2), beacause 1 nested loop. and all 2 loops iterate over all list